# Parsing the swagger API doc (swagger.json) to Java objects

Tags: swagger

I want to parse any complex swagger-API-document(swagger.json) to Java objects.

may be List>

what are available options?

I am trying with io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.

but want to make sure that I know other available options and I use the correct parser which suffices to parse any complex document.

currently we are trying as below.

```
public  List<Map<String,Object>> parse(String swaggerDocString) throws SwaggerParseException{
    try{
        Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().parse(swaggerDocString);
        return processSwagger(swagger);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        String exceptionRefId=OSGUtil.getExceptionReferenceId();
        logger.error("exception ref id " + exceptionRefId +  " : Error while loading swagger file " + ex);
        throw new SwaggerParseException("", ex.getLocalizedMessage(),exceptionRefId);
    }
}

public  List<Map<String,Object>> processSwagger(Swagger swagger){
    List<Map<String,Object>>  finalResult=new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Model>  definitions = swagger.getDefinitions();
    // loop all the available paths of the swagger
    if(swagger.getPaths()!=null && swagger.getPaths().keySet()!=null &&swagger.getPaths().keySet().size()>0 ){
        swagger.getPaths().keySet().forEach(group->{
            //get the path
            Path path=swagger.getPath(group);
            //list all the operations of the path
            Map<HttpMethod,Operation> mapList=path.getOperationMap();
            mapList.forEach((httpMethod,operation)->{
                processPathData(finalResult,operation,path,group,httpMethod,definitions,group);
            });

        });
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

whats the differences between

swagger-compat-spec-parser, 
swagger-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swagger has the implementations for all the technologies.
https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/

and details for parsing swagger into Java is here.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/tree/v1